# choosing Mocking framework for Spring JUnit

Tags: spring, mocking, junit4

I am working in Spring based project. My client has asked to write JUnit test cases for my service and DAO layer.
I have to take a decision regarding the Mocking framework I am going to use and same is to be conveyed to the client as soon as possible.
I have never used any Mocking framework before. I have heard of some like Mockito,JMock,EasyMock etc while googling on net. But didn't get any compelling answer for which one I should use.
So, I need some help choosing the right mocking framework.

Comment: IMO there isn't a compelling answer to choose one over another; I mostly use Mockito and EasyMock, both with PowerMock. I *prefer* Mockito over any of them. If *you* can't come up with a reason or preference, and you *know* your requirements and needs, I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: Sorry. There is no "right" answer. I don't think you can go horribly wrong with any of those you mentioned.

Comment: @Dave,John - I understood what you said but the issue is client,who is a technical architect, may be aware of these mocking frameworks and if i say to him that i am going to use any framework then i must be able to justify my selection and since this is the first time I will be using mocking framework so i am bit a confused. I hope you understand my situation

Comment: Then tell him that you're not experienced with mocking frameworks, but that Mockito is a very well-known projects, used by many well-known projects, and is just a wise choice. You can say the same for EasyMock.

Comment: @anand What JB said. You've backed yourself into a corner by (a) not having tests in the first place, and (b) not being familiar with well-known mocking frameworks. You essentially need to answer without saying anything that can be questioned.

Answer (score 2):

As other comments have said, there isn't a definitively *right* answer for this, but I would definitely suggest going with Mockito, for a few reasons:

- It provides much better error descriptions than most of the others. Verifications that fail will return exceptions explaining exactly what other calls occurred, where, and with what arguments, making debugging very simple.
- It has a clear advantage over older frameworks like EasyMock: Mockito created and has very effectively implemented a far nicer model for mocking than the old record/replay/verify process that EasyMock, JMock and others follow. This is very intuitive and quite easy to get the hang of, and results in far cleaner and easier to maintain tests.
- Its model has also become directly popular in many other languages (e.g. Moq), and is closer to mocking styles in dynamic languages. This makes it pretty simple to find other people familiar with it, and makes it easier for you to later use other tools.
- It's rapidly becoming the standard framework used for mocking in Java projects: I work on automated testing in projects for many companies, and I've seen a substantial number of them either already using Mockito, and actively migrating to it. Searching for 'easymock mockito' comes up with many results for migrating to Mockito from EasyMock, and none in the other direction.

There's more details of the exact differences between EasyMock and Mockito at https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockitoVSEasyMock.

More generally, I would avoid using frameworks like PowerMock unless absolutely required. PowerMock allows you to mock various elements of the codebase that normal mocking frameworks won't, but the fact you need to mock these is normally a strong indicator of some other underlying design problem. If you find yourself unable to test something without using PowerMock, you should really consider whether the structure of the code being tested could be refactored insteard (e.g. to move away from dependencies on static methods, to better use dependency injection to avoid calling constructors, etc).

I'd also suggest you also read Martin Fowler's [excellent introduction](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) to mocking. This is a little outdated now in terms of the frameworks discussed, but does still offers a really great overview to the main concepts with some nice examples.